# What are recommended (working) permissions for a user to view all SQL Agent jobs

Tags: sql-server-2012, permissions, sql-server-agent

A new user (associated with an existing login) is created in msdb and assigned membership:

```
use [msdb];
create user [TheUser] for login [AnExistingLogin];
alter role [SQLAgentUserRole] add member [TheUser];
alter role [SQLAgentReaderRole] add member [TheUser];

-- Impersonate the user via an SP in another DB with execute as...
select top 10 * from msdb.dbo.sysjobs; -- fail

The SELECT permission was denied on the object 'sysjobs', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.
```

Try the obvious:

```
grant select on msdb.dbo.sysjobs to [TheUser]

select top 10 * from msdb.dbo.sysjobs; -- success
```

Isn't the  proper way to work within the SQLAgent* roles?

[SO question with competing answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370881/the-select-permission-was-denied-on-the-object-sysjobs-database-msdb-schem)

[Blog on SQLAgentReaderRole](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/how-do-i-assign-permissions-to-users-to-see-sql-agent-jobs/)

Comment: I remember trying to deal with this a long time back, and I remember trying to mess with proxies and trustworthy databases and all kinds of hacks and eventually threw my hands in the air and created stored procedures - with execute as owner - and granted the user explicit rights to those.